# Webpack Can't Read JSON File

Tags: webpack

I'm using webpack in order to create an admin panel which I run on localhost.

I'm trying to read a local JSON file and display the data as HTML like so:

**My Json**

```html
{
    "key1": {"val":"1", "val2":"2"},
    "key2": {"val":"3", "val2":"4"},
    "key3": {"val":"5", "val2":"6"}
}
```

**my index.js:**

```html
const raw = require('./assets/json/raw/raw.json');

const fetchJSON = () => {
    fetch(raw)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching JSON:', error));
}
```

**My webpack.config:**

```html
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/, // This pattern will only apply the loaders to .html files
        use: ['html-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        enforce: "pre",
        use: ['source-map-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/, // Add a new rule for handling JSON files
        use: ['file-loader']
      },
    ],
  },
```

**The Error I receive:**

```html
ERROR in ./src/assets/json/raw/raw.json
Module parse failed: Cannot parse JSON: Unexpected token 'e', "export def"... is not valid JSON while parsing 'export default __webpack_public_path__ +'
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: Cannot parse JSON: Unexpected token 'e', "export def"... is not valid JSON while parsing 'export default __webpack_public_path__ +'
```

It's basically saying my JSON is invalid, which isn't true, which leads me to believe it's loading it incorrectly somehow.

**Edit:**
I originally used this function to read JSON files, but my webpack can't load 'fs' modules:

```html
exports.ReadFile = (async(file_path) => {
  try {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(file_path, 'utf8')
  
    // parse JSON string to JSON object
    const obj = JSON.parse(data)
    // console.log(`[ReadFile]: obj = ${obj}`);

    return obj;

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error reading file from disk: ${err}`)
  }
});
```

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

Comment: It is saying that your `raw.json` files starts out with Javascript code.

Comment: Why do you try to load a local file with fetch? fetch is for http requests not for file systems. `require` is bundeld into a module that `exports` its content. So it not contain only json. (`export default ...`)

Comment: @Marc I understand, thank you for the clarification! I edited my post, please check it out!

Comment: Is this a node.js app or a "spa" that runs in the browser?

Comment: @Marc, It's a web app that's running on localhost. I need it to update my database on firestore. I'm loading the json locally to view & edit the data before I update my database.